# AES encryption with Go and PHP

Tags: php, encryption, go, aes, rijndael

I am using AES encryption in Go and PHP. But both the languages does not encrypt/decrypt each other ciphertext. Following i have tried in php

```
       class Crypto {
    private $encryptKey = "keyforencryption";
    private $iv = 'ivusedforencrypt';
    private $blocksize = 16;
    public function encrypt($toEncrypt){
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
        //$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return base64_encode($this->iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->encryptKey, $toEncrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $this->iv));
    }

    public function decrypt($toDecrypt){
       $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);//$this->blocksize;
       $toDecrypt = base64_decode($toDecrypt);
       return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->encryptKey, substr($toDecrypt, $iv_size), MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, substr($toDecrypt, 0, $iv_size)));
    }

}

$c = new Crypto();
echo "Encrypted : ".$e =  $c->encrypt("test");
echo "<br/>Decrypted : ".$c->decrypt($e);
```

output : aXZ1c2VkZm9yZW5jcnlwdDpdZEinU2rB

and this one in Go with AES

```
    package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    key := []byte("keyforencryption")
    plaintext := []byte("test")
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", plaintext)
    ciphertext, err := encrypt(key, plaintext)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    b := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext)
    fmt.Printf("Encrypted text : %s\n", b)
    result, err := decrypt(key, b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Decrypted Text : %s\n", result)
}

func encrypt(key, text []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    //b := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(text)
    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(text))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    cfb.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], []byte(text))
    return ciphertext, nil
}

func decrypt(key []byte, text1 string) ([]byte, error) {
    text, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(text1))
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if len(text) < aes.BlockSize {
        return nil, errors.New("ciphertext too short")
    }
    iv := text[:aes.BlockSize]
    text = text[aes.BlockSize:]
    cfb := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)
    cfb.XORKeyStream(text, text)
    b := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(text)
    data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(b))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return data, nil
}
```

output : ZVnhCXjIvtGKBdqvjwHRZKcVy34=

any help would be appreciable.

Comment: *"But both the languages does not encrypt/decrypt each other ciphertext."* - Please give some example inputs and outputs. I can see that at least one difference: there's base64 encoding/decoding in Go, but hex decoding in PHP.

Comment: Updated the code with fix the hex and base64 difference and output.

Comment: Well, further problems: IV in Go is `\0` filled, but is `ivusedforencrypt` in PHP.

Comment: In both iv gives 16 in length.

Comment: Yes, they have the IVs have the same length, but they not the same. Also, I think that mcrypt's CFB mode has a bug, because it seems to be using padding.

Comment: mcrypt *is* the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CFB mode has an issue, this will work in CBC mode

```
class Crypto {
    private $encryptKey = "keyforencryption";
    public function encrypt($toEncrypt){
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return base64_encode($iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->encryptKey, $toEncrypt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    }

    public function decrypt($toDecrypt){
       $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
       echo "<br/>".$toDecrypt = base64_decode($toDecrypt);
       return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $this->encryptKey, substr($toDecrypt, $iv_size), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, substr($toDecrypt, 0, $iv_size)));
    }
}

$c = new Crypto();
echo "Encrypted : ".$e =  $c->encrypt("test123");
echo "<br/>Decrypted : ".$c->decrypt($e);
```

and this one in golang

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    e:= cbcEncrypt()
    fmt.Printf("Encrypted String : %s\n", e)

    d:= cbcDecrypt(e)
    fmt.Printf("Decrypted String : %s\n", d)
}

func cbcDecrypt(text1 string) []byte{
    key := []byte("keyforencryption")
    ciphertext, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(text1))
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // include it at the beginning of the ciphertext.
    if len(ciphertext) < aes.BlockSize {
        panic("ciphertext too short")
    }
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    ciphertext = ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:]

    // CBC mode always works in whole blocks.
    if len(ciphertext)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
        panic("ciphertext is not a multiple of the block size")
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)

    // CryptBlocks can work in-place if the two arguments are the same.
    mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext, ciphertext)
    ciphertext = PKCS5UnPadding(ciphertext)
    return ciphertext
}

func cbcEncrypt() string{
    key := []byte("keyforencryption")
    plaintext := []byte("testssssss")
    plaintext = PKCS5Padding(plaintext, 16)
    // CBC mode works on blocks so plaintexts may need to be padded to the
    // next whole block. For an example of such padding, see
    // https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-6.2.3.2. Here we'll
    // assume that the plaintext is already of the correct length.
    if len(plaintext)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
        panic("plaintext is not a multiple of the block size")
    }

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // The IV needs to be unique, but not secure. Therefore it's common to
    // include it at the beginning of the ciphertext.
    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)

    // It's important to remember that ciphertexts must be authenticated
    // (i.e. by using crypto/hmac) as well as being encrypted in order to
    // be secure.

    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext)
}

func PKCS5Padding(src []byte, blockSize int) []byte {
    padding := blockSize - len(src)%blockSize
    padtext := bytes.Repeat([]byte{byte(padding)}, padding)
    return append(src, padtext...)
}

func PKCS5UnPadding(src []byte) []byte {
    length := len(src)
    unpadding := int(src[length-1])
    return src[:(length - unpadding)]
}
```

this should work

Comment: This still gives different results in my case. I'm trying to use this for PayTM gateway integration in Go. Do you have any clues?

Comment: This example gives you different results because the $iv is a random value (better security). But decoder function can decode both PHP and GO encoded texts.

Answer (score 1):

Also use padding for encoding and unpadding for decode in php.

```
function pkcs5_pad($text)
{
    $blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function pkcs5_unpad($text)
{
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $pad = ord($text[($len = strlen($text)) - 1]);
    $len = strlen($text);
    $pad = ord($text[$len-1]);
    return substr($text, 0, strlen($text) - $pad);
}
```